# Splitting a string with php incrementally

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP that I would like to split. This string is concatenation of ID numbers from the database.

An example of the string is below but it could be much long with each ID separated by "_":

ID_1_10_11_12

I would like to split the string into the following:

ID_1_10_11_12

ID_1_10_11

ID_1_10

ID_1

Then concatenate them in a new string reversed in order and then separated by spaces:

new string = "ID_1 ID_1_10 ID_1_10_11 ID_1_10_11_12"

I cant figure this out. I have tried exploding the original value into an array by "_" but that just leaves me with the numbers.

I would appreciate any advice on how I should approach this. For reference these ID's written to the class value of a checkbox so that parent and child values can be grouped and then manipulated by a jquery function.

Comment: You're doing something really really wrong if you're doing this. Do you understand arrays?

Comment: Seems like OP is trying to create a new form of encryption.

Comment: You may find recursion useful here.

Comment: Any reason the IDs couldn't be put directly into an array instead of a "_" concatenated string when you first pull them out of the database? It would save a step or two of string manipulation and be much easier to work with.

Comment: If you explode the string, you'll get an array with the numeric values in the order you wanted. You could just reverse that array and then iterate over slices from it to build the reversed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way, and it'll break if there are less than 2 IDs, but this will return the string you asked for:

```
$str = "ID_1_10_11_12";

//creates an array with all elements
$arr = explode("_", $str);

$new_str = ' ID_' . $arr[1];
for ($i=2; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    $tmp =  explode(" ", $new_str);
    $new_str .= " " . $tmp[$i-1] . "_" . $arr[$i];
}
$new_str = trim($new_str);

echo $new_str; //echoes ID_1 ID_1_10 ID_1_10_11 ID_1_10_11_12
```

I don't see much usability for it but there you go.

You can then simply `explode(" ", $new_str)` and you'll also have an array with all the elements in that string, which you can transverse the way you want.

Obviously, you can also add a `if (count($arr) < 3)` before the `for` to check if there are less than 2 array elements after the `ID` and exit the function printing the `$new_str` without the white space with `trim($new_str)` if inputting less than 2 ID arrays is a concern.

**edit:** Trimmed the left white space.

Answer (score 0):

My testing local server is down to verify this, but I believe this will work.

```
<?php
/*

ID_1_10_11_12
ID_1_10_11
ID_1_10
ID_1

ID_1 ID_1_10 ID_1_10_11 ID_1_10_11_12

*/
$str = "ID_1_10_11_12";
$delim = "_";
$spacer = " ";
$ident = "ID";
$out = "";

// make an array of the IDs
$idList = explode($delim, $str);

// loop through the array
for($cur = 0; $cur >= count($idList); $cur++){
    // reset the holder
    $hold = $ident;

    // loop the number of times as the position beyond 0 we're at
    for($pos = -1; $pos > $cur; $pos++){

        // add the current id to the holder
        $hold .= $delim . $idList[$cur]; // "ID_1"
    }

    // add a spacer and the holder to the output if we aren't at the beginning,
    //      otherwise just add the holder
    $out .= ($cur != 0 ? $spacer . $hold : $hold); // "ID_1 ID_1_10"
}
// output the result
echo $out;

?>
```