# Append every array element to the previous array elements inside of a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, concatenation, append

I know how to split my input string on spaces, but I need to generate an array of values where each element contains the previous string PLUS the next available word.

```
$str = "a nice and sunny day today";
$split = explode(' ', $str);
```

How could I possibly be left with an array that looks like the following:

```
$new[0] = 'a';
$new[1] = 'a nice';
$new[2] = 'a nice and';
$new[3] = 'a nice and sunny';
```

Instead of manually doing this

```
$new[] = $split[0];
$new[] = $split[0] . $split[1];
$new[] = $split[0] . $split[1] . $split[2];
$new[] = $split[0] . $split[1] . $split[2] . $split[3];
```

You can probably see the pattern that's happening.

Because this can happen for up to around 15 words, I'm seeking a shorter and dynamic way of doing this using a foreach/some kind of function.

Comment: Topically related, not a duplicate: [phrase split algorithm in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787038/2943403)

Comment: Also related: [Splitting a string with php incrementally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10560783/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = array();
$new = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($split); $i++)
  {
    $tmp[] = $split[$i];
    $new[] = implode(' ',$tmp);
  }
```

Shorter code, reverse order:

```
$new = array();
for($i = count($split); $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
    $new[] = implode(' ',$split);
    array_pop($split);
  }
```

Which of course is not a problem according to [array_reverse()](http://php.net/array_reverse)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$str = "a nice and sunny day today";
$split = explode(' ', $str);

$newList = array();
// Non-empty string?
if($str) {
    // Add the first element
    $newList[] = $split[0];
    for($i = 1; $i < count($split); $i++) {
        // New element gets appended with previous
        $newList[] = $newList[$i-1] . " " . $split[$i];
    }
}
```

This is more efficient than executing `implode` every time, since we're only concatenating the current and previous string.

There's one more bit of inefficiency though - we're calling `count` every time. Lets not do that.

```
$newList[] = $split[0]
for($i = 1, $len = count($split); $i < $len; $i++) {
    // New element gets appended with previous
    $newList[] = $newList[$i-1] . " " . $split[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "1 2 3";
$split = explode(' ', $str);
/* 
now $split is array('1','2','3')

Need to convert it to: array('1','1 2','1 2 3')
*/
$n = count($split);
$output = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    $output[$i] = "";
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; ++$j)
    {
        $output[$i] .= $split[$j];
        if ($j != $i)
        {
            $output[$i] .= " ";
        }
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "1 2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "1 2 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build the string in a loop and add to your array.

```
$str = "a nice and sunny day today";
$split = explode(' ', $str);
$final_array = array();

$i = 0;
$string = '';
$spacer = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($split); $i++) {
    $string .= $spacer . $split[$i];
    $final_array[] = $string;
    $spacer = ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with a callback function to achieve this:

```
$result = array_filter(array_map(function($k) use($split) { 
    return implode(' ', array_slice($split, 0, $k)); 
}, array_keys($split)));

print_r(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a nice
    [2] => a nice and
    [3] => a nice and sunny
    [4] => a nice and sunny day
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/76306)

Answer (score 0):

I lean, direct solution should not be using more than one loop or more than one function call (after exploding, of course).

I'll demonstrate a functional-style solution with `array_map()`.  The `static` declaration allows a value to be retained for access during subsequent iterations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Yonqf)) ([Uglier version](https://3v4l.org/CpNC4))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($word) {
            static $last;                            // declare persistent variable in scope
            $word = ($last ? "$last " : '') . $word; // prepend previous word(s)
            return $last = $word;                    // update $last and return $word (which is identical to $last)
        },
        explode(' ', $str)
    )
);
```

Or as shown in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73322810/2943403): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5Zhb4))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($word) {
            static $last;
            return ltrim($last .= " $word");
        },
        explode(' ', $str)
    )
);
```