# PHP, Combining each array item to the previous ones

Tags: php, arrays

I am building breadcrumbs and I would like to do it from all segments from the current url.
I am getting the array that looks like this

```
$segments = [0 =>'users',
             1 =>'index',
             2 =>'all'];
```

I'd like to combine the array in this way :

```
$routes = [ 0 =>'users',
            1 =>'users/index',
            2 =>'users/index/all'];
```

I have tried using array_map

```
            $segs = array_map(function($a){return $a."/".$a;},$segments);
```

but it combines the same array item twice

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a loop that goes over the array, concats the current string and adds the value to a new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through each element and take an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) from the start until the current element, which you then simply can [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with a slash.

```
<?php

    $segments = ["users", "index", "all"];

    foreach($segments as $k => $v)
        $result[] = implode("/", array_slice($segments, 0, ($k+1)));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => users
    [1] => users/index
    [2] => users/index/all
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using `array_map()` same as @[Rizier123's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) method,

```
$segments = ['users','index','all'];

$routes = array_map(function($v, $k) use ($segments){
            return implode('/', array_slice($segments, 0, ($k+1)));
        }, $segments, array_keys($segments));
```

Comment: You may also want to initialize `$till_now`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to fix this issue :

```
$arr = array(0 =>'users', 1 =>'index', 2 =>'all');
print_r(returnPath($arr));

function returnPath($urlArr = null){
    $index = 1; $sep='';
    $length = count($urlArr);
    foreach($urlArr as $key => $item){   
        if($index > 1 && $index < $length){ $sep = '/'; }

        $temp .= $sep.$item; 
        $urlArr[$key] = $temp; 

    $index++;
    }

    return $urlArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slicing and imploding on every iteration, you can concatenate and ltrim instead.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8l48V))

```
$segments = ["users", "index", "all"];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            static $path = '';
            return ltrim($path .= "/$v", '/');
        },
        $segments
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'users',
  1 => 'users/index',
  2 => 'users/index/all',
)
```